# How to Copy Area Hierarchy from One TFS Team Project to Another?

Tags: tfs, team-project

I have created a new Team Project using a different process template but a branch of the existing code.

Is there a way to copy the Area hierarchy from the original Team Project to the new one? I'd hate to have to enter it all by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area Import/Export Tool:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/07/08/updated-area-import-export-tool-for-tfs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an immediate way to do this in VS.

Shai Raiten has blogged about getting Areas/Iterations [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-9-get-area-iteration-programmatically.aspx) & adding them programmatically [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-10-add-area-iteration-programmatically.aspx) using TFS-API. These could probably be used as a basis to implement your copy/paste activities.